# Não consigo Ler arquivo parquet em datalake da forma esperada com python

Tags: python, pandas, microsoft-azure

estou com uma POC para consumir dados de um datalake via python, li a documentação consegui alguns avanços mas ainda não consegui fazer um retorno do arquivo em sí para fazer a leitura do mesmo de forma efetiva para poder trabalhar estes dados, não sou nenhum expert em python mas estou estudando para tentar desenrolar de acordo com as demandas. A minha função de leitura me retorna apenas arquivos binários pois segundo a documentação, assim que eu faço o dowload do arquivo em especifico ele fica salvo em stream, logo eu devo efetuar a chamada redall para que seja possível ler os arquivos em stream, porém os mesmos são retornados todos de uma forma que eu não consigo fazer a leitura, a minha intenção é trazer o arquivo .parquet para ler ele pelo pandas e posteriormente tratar este dado. Alguem consegue me ajudar ?

segue a função abaixo

Fiz a chamada da função da seguinte maneira

dowload_file_blob_storage("nome do container", "Nome do arquivo.parquet")

```
def dowload_file_blob_storage(container_name, blob_name):
CONNECTION_STRING = os.environ['AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING']
try:
    CONNECTION_STRING 

except KeyError:
    print("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING must be set.")
    sys.exit(1)

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
try:
    data = blob_client.download_blob().readall() # <- não tenho certeza se é este método mesmo que poderia ser usado para ler o arquivo
    """
    aqui eu preciso que a minha função faça a leitura do arquivo parquet e retorne o dataframe
    """
    
    print(data)
except ExecError as err:
    print("An error occurred when downloading blob {}".format(err))
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda: [pandas.read_parquet()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html)

Comment: Já tentei utilizar este método porem idependente se uso ele ou não eu tenho o retorno de algo parecido com isto sempre

"xd1\x8b\x00\xa1\x12Q\x0b\x089\xc0\xc1%\xf4\x0c(\xc4\xbd\xbf\x0e\xb9\x0b\x0c\xbcG\xea\xeb\x05O\x11\x08\x04\x07\xc7V`\x05\x00\xbe~\x9b\x00\x05x\x1c\xc2\xc3\x96\x97\x98\x99\xec\xe75\x98\x16\x18\x14\x1a\x9a\x0c\x00\xe8\x12L\r\x08ABC!\\%\xe7\x04MN%l\x18)*+,\xc6\xe9\xe9\x05\x13I\x15)\xcfZv\x02\x00\x8d~\x8c\x01"

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta e mostrar como usou a função?

Comment: Sim vou editar. fiz a chamada da seguinte maneira

Comment: Não entendi, pelo código dá a entender queria ler o conteúdo de `data = blob_client.download_blob().readall()` como parquet, mas a linha que apresentou `dowload_file_blob_storage("nome do container", "Nome do arquivo.parquet")` dá a entender que é um arquivo no disco? Onde uso da função `pandas.read_parquet()`? Ai não tem condições de fazer uma análise.

Comment: @AugustoVasques no caso estou tentando ler um arquivo em um datalake da azure, no caso ultilizo por meio desse blob_client já a conexão no container e dentro desse container consigo escutar alguns arquivos por meio da biblioteca BlobServiceClient, e ela tem a propriedade dowload_blob que recebe por parametro o blob_name que é o nome do arquivo que é passado na chamada da função, e ele armazena isso em stream, o comando redall é para fazer um "dispach" deste arquivo porém ele não é legivel do parquet, aparentemente o redall já está fazendo uma leitura porém não no formato que eu gostaria.

Comment: Em tese ao receber o valor na variável data seria somente eu fazer um pandas.read_parquet(data)

ele não retorna um erro na leitura porém o formato de retorno é o mesmo de simplesmente não fazer o read_parquet(data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela sua pergunta usando a referencia abaixo somente precisa apontar a URL SAS dentro do pandas: `pandas.read_parquet('URL SAS')`
dentro do ADL GEN2 em tokens compartilhados defina uma validade e o tipo de permissão e gere o token.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70261687/how-to-read-parquet-files-directly-from-azure-datalake-without-spark

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Deu super certo tamo junto efetuei a seguinte solução

Resolução do problema, eu estava tentando acessar o arquivo em uma biblioteca que me retornaria um binário em stream, encontrei uma solução fazendo a leitura do arquivo diretamente por uma rota direto dentro do DataLake com o a autorizalção de um sasToken gerado pela Azure



ficou da seguinte forma
Source = http:container.blob.core.window.net/container/pasta/arquivo.parquet?sp=Token



eu apenas efetuo a chamada via pandas com
df = pd.read_parquet(source)